# Run setInterval function within mapping of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am mapping an array to display rows in a table dynamically. I have a "dtmStart" field that is the start time for a contest. I am wanting to display a countdown to the start time, and have it update every second. How can I accomplish this within the mapping function? Here is my current component.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";

const MyUpcomingContests = (props) => {
  const moment = require("moment");

  // Run calcTime every second
  let calcTime = (date) => {
    let now = new Date().getTime();
    let start = new Date(date).getTime();

    let timeleft = start - now;

    // Calculating the days, hours, minutes and seconds left
    let days = Math.floor(timeleft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours = Math.floor(
      (timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
    );
    let minutes = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((timeleft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    let countdown = "";
    // Display the message when countdown is over, or display the countdown
    if (timeleft < 0) {
      countdown = "TIME UP!!";
    } else countdown = days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    return countdown;
  };

  return (
    <Table hover>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Contest Name</th>
          <th>Live In</th>
          <th>Game Style</th>
          <th>Entry Fee</th>
          <th>Entries</th>
          <th>Prizes</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {props.contests.map((contest) => (
          <tr key={contest.intContestID}>
            <td>Need name column</td>
            <td>
              {setInterval(() => {
                calcTime(contest.dtmStart);
              }, 1000)}
            </td>
            <td>{contest.strContestType}</td>
            <td>${contest.decEntryFee}</td>
            <td>calc entries</td>
            <td>${contest.decPrizePool}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
};

export default MyUpcomingContests;
```

The calcTime function works properly, All I need is to figure out how to run this function to continually update the field in the table row.

Comment: Use state.  Update the state on the interval.  Preferably the state should live above that component in the hierarchy, but you can just add the state to the current component.

Comment: You'd be much better off using yout `calcTime` function to update a state variable (initiated on some event, whether it be the click of a button of a `componentDidMount`), and then use that state variable inside your `<td>`.  React will handle updating it for you - that's the idea behind react.

Comment: I thought about using state, however there are multiple rows that would be needing to update every second so I don't think a state variable would work here. I could update the contests array from the parent component and rerender this, however that seems rather expensive for only wanting to update a single field in each row. Maybe I am mistaken with that assumption.

Comment: a state change each second is not inefficient, you will be fine unless you have massive data changes and rendering changes, which it doesn't look like you don't.

Comment: If you really _must_, you can store a (DOM) ref and update it manually in uncontrolled component style. But I doubt you will be able to do it much more (if at all) efficiently than React can, because the change detection and VDOM is very, very good at what it does, and it is thus not going to be worth the complexity and inelegance of the code you will generate doing it yourself. And really, at that point, pagination and infinite tables (or something similar) to keep DOM elements under control will be the bottleneck.